# Change Android NDK location in Windows 10

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a Windows 10 with a 128GB C SSD drive. Somehow, many applications have a nasty habit of installing on C and they do not work on other partitions. So I am struggling for every bit of empty space, because the drive is permanently full. I have already moved Android SDK and Java SDK. However, the Android NDK is in a special folder - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft.

Is it safe to move the Android NDK from this folder to another drive? Will it not brake my development environment?

Comment: I've done this in the past. Just change the NDK path in your IDE (and anywhere else where you've entered it) afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is 100% safe. Just move the the NDK to the location you want it to be in and change the NDK path in your IDE.